# I've got a problem with recursion in my code

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

so I have a problem with editing my code. I need it to work as it's working now but without recursion. I've tried using 'for' and 'while' loops but it didn't work.
Here's the code:

```js
function calcFactorial(num) {
  var outcome = factorial(num);

  if (outcome > 0) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<h3 style'color:blue;'>factorial of number " + num + " = " + outcome + "</h3>";
  }
}

function factorial(num) {
  if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (num < 0) {
    error();
    return -1;
  }
  var outcome = num * factorial(num - 1);

  return outcome;
}

function error() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<h3 style='color:red;'>Error, you can not calculate factorial of that number! </h3>";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Factorial</h1>

  <form name="myForm">
    <p> <b>Type a number:</b>
      <input type="number" name="myNumber" value="0" size=2 id="abcde"> </p>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcFactorial(document.myForm.myNumber.value)">
  </form>

  <p id="result"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

P.S. sorry if i wrote something that makes no logical sense, but i'm not a native speaker and i am still learning.

Comment: How exactly isn't it working? What's the actual output vs expected output?

Comment: "javascript calculate factorial while loop" Use your favorite search engine.

Comment: @mykaf I mean it is working but i just need that code working the same way without recursion in it. By 'working the same way' i mean calculating factorial of given number.

Comment: Update your post to show your attempts with `for` or `while`.

Comment: Initialize the result variable to 1. Then use a `for` loop that runs from 2 to num, multiplying the result by the current element of the loop.